# Шаблонизатор PHP -  вредно или полезно?

Tags: шаблоны, php, шаблонизаторы

Очень нашумела тема - шаблонизаторы php. Лично я не могу найти простой шаблонизатор, который, хотя бы отделял **логику** от **разметки**, под логикой я подразумеваю серверную часть. Тут помогают довольно умные программисты и поэтому у меня вопрос; стоит ли использовать шаблонизатор например, Вконтакте (если кто знает) использует ли шаблонизатор? и вообще как будет лучше - использовать шаблонизатор или писать все вместе. Почему я задаю этот вопрос? т.к есть желание разрабатывать довольно крупный проект и сейчас необходимо много советов. Допустим, я буду разрабатывать социальную сеть (полноценную), ведь вопрос стоит в том, что в будущем, когда захочется поменять шаблон придется перебирать кучу кода. Может быть - можно документировать и описать все подробно что где лежит. Помогите с выбором:

- Шаблонизатор php
- Писать все вместе (логику и шаблон)

Я лично придерживаюсь мнением, что ДЛЯ ТАКИХ САЙТОВ, который хочу разрабатывать уже требуется шаблонизатор.

Comment: Если вы начинающий программист с небольшим стажем, то вам простительно не знать и не использовать шаблонизатор. Однозначный ответ - использовать, не важно, крупный проект или нет. 
Попробуйте понять Smarty, а вообще вопрос и архитектурного строения программы, посмотрите MVC, HMVC - модель.
Тут описаны самые популярные шаблонизаторы PHP: http://habrahabr.ru/post/75901/

Comment: два года не заходил на хешкод.. а шаблонизаторы всё еще шумят )

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk,  Smarty - очень тяжелый для  проекта. Я юзаю наитивные шаблоны и не парюсь - и работает быстро. А Smarty - можно сказать что это дань моде, когда то новая плюшка на которую смотрели как на избавление от всех бед , а в итоге как по мне больше гемора сделали. Тем более сейчас когда контекст на страницу грузится порциями (ajax) - смысл его использования впринципе отпадает

Comment: Смарти - это просто мамонт прошлого века, который не сумел развиться, как и кодигнитер. Можно, но не нужно. Сейчас лидером является Twig, который практически повторяет джанговский шаблонизатор, и, в общем-то, это скорее положительная сторона, чем отрицательная.

Comment: @Fike не скажу что Smarty знатно проигрывает. По крайней мере те функции, которые нужны мне, он прекрасно выполняет! Проблем не вижу с ним. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начал использовать шаблонизатор на своих проектах после того когда потребовалось сделать мобильную версию сайта и версию для vk. Изначально вывод хтмл кода был сразу в php функциях. Делать пачку if else и превращать код в простыню не вариант. Разделив логику и шаблоны дело пошло быстрее. Да и при смене дизайна меньше кода перелопачивать надо. Также появилась возможность сделать подобие api-шки, так как серверная часть возвращает объекты а не сформированный хтмл код.

Answer (score 4):

В MVC, в принципе шаблонизатор теряет свой смысл. Возвращаешь контроллером массив подготовленных в нем данных, а далее работать с ним. А далее работать уже на нативном PHP куда легче и приятнее чем нагружать мозг и приложение лишним кодом, тем более новые версии PHP позволяют это делать абсолютно без каких либо проблем.

Comment: ох щи

> Возвращаешь контроллером массив подготовленных в нем данных, а далее работать с ним.

так было всегда

> А далее работать уже на нативном PHP куда легче и приятнее чем нагружать мозг и приложение лишним кодом

   if (!empty($data['options']['status']))) {
       ?>
           // сложный html, с которым сложно работать через echo
       <?php echo mb_convert_case($data['options']['status'], MB_CASE_TITLE);
   }

по сравнению с "лишним кодом":

   {% if data.options.status %}
       // тот же html
       {{ data.options.status|capitalize }}
   {% endif %}

Comment: > нагружать приложение

фабпот не дурак - он не рендерит шаблон, он его [компилирует и только потом вызывает](http://pastebin.com/aErXY2E5)

> тем более новые версии PHP позволяют это делать абсолютно без каких либо проблем.

я что-то не помню ничего революционного или даже полуреволюционного в этом направлении (кроме `<?=`, но это просто синтаксический сахар)

И да, все дизайнеры конечно скажут вам спасибо за возможность писать шаблоны на пхп. И последующие мейнтейнеры проекта тоже. Я уж молчу про наследование, `parent()` и прочие плюшки.

Comment: А зачем эти if'ы, если можно и красивее как-нибудь так:

    <?php $vars->get_option('status', MYOPT_CAPITALISE); ?>

Но это я не к тому, что Шаблонизаторы - это зло, просто и на чистом PHP это во многих случаях делается вполне сносно для несложных проектов.

Comment: @MDJHD, если просто требуется вывести одну переменную, то 

    {{ data.options.status|capitalize }}

Отработает ровно так, как надо. Твиг просто перестанет выполнять выражение, когда наткнется на несущствующую переменную, либо выведет пустоту, если в переменной пустая строка.

Comment: @Fike, загляните в SHOP CMS, к примеру, потом скажите что 'так было всегда' это большая тучка "лапши" где шаблонизатор использовать здраво. 
А теперь к примеру, у меня есть контроллер, который отдает мне массив, с нужными мне данными. Все они есть, они готовы к выводу, зачем мне лишний код? Ведь задачи, в основном сводятся к <?=$data['title'] ?> или к 

<? foreach($data['items'] as $item) { ?>
    <b>Предмет: </b> <?=$item['name'] ?> <br />
<? } ?>

Ну, та же задача на smarty... 
{section name=i loop=$items}
    <b> Предмет: </b> {$items[i].name}<br />
{/section}

Comment: А когда нужна сложная логика в шаблоне, то начинают в шаблон сувать и php синтаксис и шаблонизаторва синтаксис и получается вообще трэш.
Т.е. От синтаксиса php в шаблонах не возможно избавиться, как мне кажется.

Comment: @avengerweb, всегда компоненты нижних уровней возвращали наверх данные в переменных. Большой разницы обращаться к ним по ключам массива или сразу по именам нет.

> Ведь задачи, в основном сводятся

(запятая не нужна) Простейший пример: предметов может быть ноль, нужно вывести сообщение о том, что их нет. Это как минимум двухуровневый if-foreach и та самаю лапша. У твига же for ... else - нативная конструкция.  
@Victor Halauko, "сувальщиков" надо просто увольнять, это не программисты - это раз. Нормальные шаблонизаторы не поддерживают выполнение чистого php - это два.

Comment: @Fike, от одного if\else много не измениться, да и в большинстве переборов он просто необходим. Допустим, у меня есть блок: Последние покупки, он имеет заголовок, при том мне не нужно выводить блок если он пустой. На вашем шаблонизаторе это будет выглядеть идентично. Логики в шаблоне быть не должно - это бесспорно, но сувать всюду и везде шаблонизатор, сейчас тоже не целесообразно.